# vim add custom color for angular code

Tags: macvim

I'm completely new to vim and I'm using macvim at the moment. I have installed a color scheme but it's not very good for angularjs code. I wanted to modify it to made any $scope a color and anything that follows as .function another color. Current sublimetext does this. Any help in this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?
https://github.com/othree/javascript-libraries-syntax.vim

According to README, this plugin does support syntax highlighting for Angular.